# Don't understand simple pie chart (coord_polar())

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, pie-chart

please consider the following simple data frame, where each observation/individual has multiple variables whose values add up to 1. For example, A through E could be different body parts, and each person's body parts all add up 100% of the person's total weight, but the proportions might be different between individuals:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test.df <- data.frame("Variable" = LETTERS[1:5], "Obs1"  = c(0.1, 0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2), 
                      "Obs2" = c(0.3, 0.7, 0, 0, 0))
```

This should produce the following data frame

```
> test.df
  Variable Obs1 Obs2
1        A  0.1  0.3
2        B  0.0  0.7
3        C  0.5  0.0
4        D  0.2  0.0
5        E  0.2  0.0
```

I'd like a pie chart for each observation. So, a total of two pie charts, where all the variables are shown in a legend for each chart, and the color codes match between charts, and values of '0' are represented in the legend but not on the chart itself.

I'm positive that what I'd like to do is simple, but there's some stumbling block that I'm not seeing. I've done this before successfully, but it seems I did not truly understand because now I'm having trouble. I have tried:

```
ggplot(test.df, aes(x='', y='Obs1', fill = Variable)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = 'identity') + coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

What I end up with is a pie chart where each of the five varibles take up equal amounts of space, even though I have specified that the values of 'y' should come from Obs1 in the data frame:

[image: pie chart result]

Can anyone please help me? This is driving me crazy!

Best,

A

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your data to a longer format using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to make sure you can plot two graphs for Obs1 and Obs2 using `facet_wrap` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test.df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Obs1:Obs2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x='', y= value, fill = Variable)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = 'identity') + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: THank you! This is brilliant. I will use this from now on. However, it actually wasn't the solution to my problem. Thouh, you did solve the problem in your answer - I was using quotation marks around the value for y in the y = statment in my original post. This was a no-go. 

Changing this solved the problem, but your answer is a great solution to working with a an entire data frame for making multiple pie charts.